# WPF: there is different between binding via XAML compare to code behind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

There is different between binding via `XAML` compare to code behind in terms of performance ?

Comment: No. 11 more to go... :-)

Comment: _"in terms of performance"_ - really?

Answer (score 4):

XAML is deserialized to objects, the same objects you can create with code behind. so the answer is no.

Comment: XAML is a declarative language to help developers (especially web developers) to write their UI in the most simple way. So yes =)

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger as a recent WPF/XAML developer, if you call XAML "simple" then my understanding of "simple" is flawed... but yes, you are right :-)

Comment: @Jcl is html/css simple? From my point of view XAML is easy. (I'm about to go for the microsoft exam)

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger I didn't say it wasn't "easy", I said it wasn't "simple". HTML/CSS are simple meaning that they are designed as a semantic way to describe a document and the presentation (and XML is good for that). XAML is a flawed way to serialize objects (as you say), and uses weird and definitely non-simple (again, I didn't say "easy") workarounds to overcome the limitations of XML as a syntax when defining objects for a much richer language (the programming language). XML is a syntax for storing data/documents, objects in .NET are not (or "not just") data.

Comment: The fact that I think XAML is flawed doesn't mean I know any better approaches, by the way (and I definitely put up with it)